# What is "Super Loop" in Embedded C programming language?

Tags: c, loops, embedded

What is **[Super Loop](http://www.keil.com/forum/14158/super-loop/)** in Embedded C programming language?

Comment: The infinite loop which services all the requests..

Comment: It is an endless loop where tasks are called sequentially

Comment: To begin with, the C programming language is the C programing language. It doesn't matter if you're targeting small embedded systems or big super-computers. There's no special "embedded C programming language", it's just plain C. As for the term "super loop", where did you hear about it? Where did you read about it? It's not a common term in C. And have you tried *searching* for it?

Comment: There's no need to "bandwagon-whine" at the OP. No clarification is needed, since the term is well-known to those with domain knowledge. https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Embedded_Systems/Super_Loop_Architecture. If you haven't heard of it, then that might be because you don't have the domain knowledge needed to respond to questions tagged embedded. Off you go, to find other tags.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude There is a technical report ([ISO/IEC TR 18037:2008](https://www.iso.org/standard/51126.html)) for extensions to the C programming language to support embedded processors.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This refers to the eternal loop usually located in `main()` of a "bare metal" system (no OS), since such systems can never return from main. A typical bare metal embedded system looks like this:

```
void main (void)
{
  // various initializations

  for(;;) // "super loop" or "main loop"
  {
    // do stuff
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

MCU is device which runs continuously or better, it executes instructions when power is on (in general).

So while loop is here to force MCU to do something, even if loop is empty, it will just circle around.

But it must do something as it is not the same as PC program where you have `return` at the end of main function.

If you wouldn't have *super loop* then MCU can get instruction from FLASH/RAM (whatever..) and do something stupid things as MCU don't know what it is executing. It just executes code you provide him.

By using super loop, you guarantee MCU won't just uncontrollable execute some instructions and maybe go to fail-safe area. Of course this can happen even if you have super loop but this is other topic.

```
int main() {
    //Init if you have something
    while (1) {
        //DO stuff always
    }
    return 0; //This should never happen!
}
```

Comment: The loop would be the reason why `int main()` is most likely an incorrect form to use for most compilers. Most compilers, like for example gcc, use `void main (void)` when compiling for a freestanding system.

Comment: It is not incorrect, it may just look odd. But it does not mean it is not correct.

Comment: It will generate an incorrect calling convention when main() is called from the "CRT" start-up code, pointlessly consuming extra stack memory. So yeah it is incorrect, on any freestanding system I know.

Comment: I somehow believe to static code analyzer tools that `int main` is not incorrect way of doing it. Most compilers know (even *gcc* is that smart) than it won't give you a warning if you use `int main` without return statement.

Comment: @Lundin When I do `void main` I got warning *Return type of main is not **int** [-Wmain]* in GCC.

Comment: GCC defaults to a hosted system compiler. You need to compile for freestanding systems `-ffreestanding`. Overall, lots of brainwashing have been done towards programmers when it comes to the format of main. The format is actually quite flexible, as far as the standard is concerned. https://stackoverflow.com/a/31263079/584518

Answer (score 0):

Super loop is an infinite loop which is suitable only in embedded c programming because there you have to run your code for very very long time and wants explicitly terminate when the behavior is change for your robot or whatever.
**Superloop** be like

```
while(1){

// Your code

// exit condition

}

for(;;) {

}
```

Comment: You 'while' -loop looks like a superloop, except there will be no exit. Weird 'for' -loop that in your example captures control flow after it exists the superloop, is unnecessary since as a rule superloops in embedded devices do not exit.

Answer (score 0):

Super loop (or superloop) is a design pattern that often is chosen by embedded real-time firmware developers for very small systems (especially, "bare metal" systems) in which simplicity is an important design goal.

The *super* loop ("super" means "above" in Latin) is the program's top-level loop. An especially simple implementation might look like this:

```c
int main() {
    initializeGlobalState();
    while (1) {
        sampleInputs();
        updateGlobalStateBasedOnNewInputs();
        updateOutputs();
    }

    // can't ever get here but the compiler may require a `return` statement.
    return 0;
}
```

Simplicity is the goal, but the pattern allows for small complications. For example, one could implement a rudimentary priority scheme:

```c
initializeGlobalState();
while (1) {
    sampleHighPriorityInputs();
    if (updateStateBasedOnNewHighPriorityInputs()) {
        updateOutputs();
        continue;
    }
    sampleOtherInputs();
    updateGlobalStateBasedOnNewOtherInputs();
    updateOutputs();
}
```

One can do scheduling:

```c
initializeGlobalState();
while (1) {
    timeNow=readFreeRunningTimer();
    sampleInputs();
    updateGlobalState();
    if (timeNow > task1_dueDate) {
        doTask1();
        task1_dueDate += task1_fixedPeriod;
    }
    if (timeNow > task2_dueDate) {
        doTask2();
        task2_dueDate = computeTask2DueDateBasedOnGlobalStateOrInputs();
    }
    ...
    updateOutputs();
}
```

One can slow things down to save power:

```c
initializeGlobalState();
enableHeartbeatInterrupt();
while (1) {
    ...
    WAIT_FOR_INTERRUPT;
}
```

Other complications are possible, but the down side of superloop is, it becomes unwieldy and brittle if you try to add too many of them. When that happens, the developer may find themselves wishing they had built the project on a Real-time OS and/or an application framework.

Answer (score 0):

**Super Loop:** It is mega or can be say that infinite loop which make architect Firmware code in much simpler firmware. it mainly includes the read I/p , process of I/p Data and the set O/p.

- It Doesn't run on RTOS or OS. i.e no chance of scheduling or asynchronous code task.

Cope Snipet:
`if ((uint8_t)(cur_tick_ms - last_print_time_ms) >= 100)  { printf("Print time! curr_tick_ms = %i\n", cur_tick_ms);`  last_print_time_ms = cur_tick_ms;}``